# How does props parameter work in HOC in React ES6?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, react-props, higher-order-components

As I've heard, when it comes to arrow functions(ES6) as HOC such as,

```
const c = a => b => {
    return(<a>{b}</a>)
}
```

can be converted into ES5 code like below:

```
const c = function(a){
    return function(b){
        return(<a>{b}</a>);
    }
}
```

As above, the following example with "props" parameter in ES6:

```
const withDisplayTrack = WrappedComponent => props => {
    const { children, onClick, handleClick, times, ..._props } = props;
    return (
        <WrappedComponent>
          {children} <small>({times} times clicked)</small>
        </WrappedComponent>
    );
}
```

will be converted into ES5 like below:

```
const withDisplayTrack = function(WrappedComponent){

     return function(props){
           const { children, onClick, handleClick, times, ..._props } = props;
           return(
                <WrappedComponent>
                  {children} <small>({times} times clicked)</small>
                </WrappedComponent>
           );
      }
}
```

However, When it comes to the code right above, I don't understand how the `props` parameter is passed down from the parent Component of `WrapperComponent`.

To be more specific, in ES5 code, although inside function is only returning the function that has `props` as parameter, how does parameter `props` has the actual props value of `withDisplayTrack` and has all the props like `{ children, onClick, handleClick, times, ..._props }`?. For me, It seems hard to find any connections between `withDisplayTrack`'s actual props with `props` parameter in the returned function.

Thank you for your help.

Edit) I forgot to mention a premise that actual props is passed down from the parent Component of `withDisplayTrack`.